# Attempting to replicate the examples of BingMapsRESTToolkit, receiving null responses from the API call inside my C# console app.

Tags: c#, rest, bing-maps

After much googling and trawling for the past day I cannot get the BingMapsRESTToolkit to work as expected using their example code on Github. I have all correct dependancies  installed (including the BingMapsRESTToolkit) and my current code looks like so.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var apiCall = ApiCallAsync();
    }

     static async Task ApiCallAsync()
    {

        var request = new GeocodeRequest()
        {
            Query = "New York, NY",
            IncludeIso2 = true,
            IncludeNeighborhood = true,
            MaxResults = 25,
            BingMapsKey = ApiKey //Referencing a string constant here declared at the top of the project which is my Bing Query key from Azure.
        };


        var response = await ServiceManager.GetResponseAsync(request);
        if (response != null &&
            response.ResourceSets != null &&
            response.ResourceSets.Length > 0 &&
            response.ResourceSets[0].Resources != null &&
            response.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0)
        {
            var result = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location;

            Console.WriteLine(result.Name.Length); // just a simple log in order to see if the request has definitely worked
        }
    }
```

After,  adding breakpoints to the response line it claims the response is currently null. There is also no output on the console proving that the WriteLine is not hit.

My question, is there anything blatantly causing there to be null returns from the API call?

Comment: Try getting rid of the await and run synchronously and see what happens.

Comment: Where is the result object initially referenced?

Comment: @jdweng unable to get rid of the await for the creating the response. As the ability to access the ResourceSets requires the response to be an awaited ServiceManager async response.

Comment: @RexCoolCodeCharles Result is only created if the result and its properties are not null. As stated with the breakpoint debugging response is set to null upon hitting the breakpoint. After trying to write to console directly after assigning the response, the code is never hit.

Comment: A stream in Net does not have an EOF unless the stream is closed.  So you r code never knows when the end of data is reached.  As soon as you send the Get response (which actually sends the request data) the stream is null.  So you never get to the console write because it is still null.  The only way of detecting the end of the response is using the event EndGetResponse.  And this doesn't always work if there is Java running on the webpage. The java may update even after the response finishes.

Answer (score 0):

After much more troubleshooting, It turns out the code was good enough for that time. However, due to being not much other than the API call in the main method it did not have enough time to get the response for the API call. My solution for this was to put a 15 sec sleep on the thread in the main method which was enough time for the separate thread to get its response and for the rest of the ApiCallAsync to run all of its code.